# Geodesic circles on $2$-sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Consider the 2-sphere $S^2$ with a smooth Riemannian metric $g$ and induced distance function $d$, pick a point $p\in S^2$. For small $r>0$, geodesic circles $S(p,r):=\{q\in S^2\mid d(p,q)=r\}$ are simple closed curves. Is this true (or under what asumptions is it true) for all $r>0$ (if $S(r,p)$ is not the empty set or a single point)?

Comment: You cannot expect this to be true as soon as you reach the cut locus of $p$, where the exponential map seizes to be injective. On the standard sphere you will get a geodesic circle which is a point -- if you consider this a simple closed curve then fine -- and if you enlarge $r$ you'll get the empty set. There is a nice paper by Philip Hartmann (I think it was published in the fifties) which rather completely analyzes the distance sets to a curve in two dimensional manifolds which you might want to look up if you want to find out the hairy details of this kind of question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have excluded where you get a single point or the empty set. Are you familiar with an example with a disconnected geodesic circle?

Comment: How about taking the standard unit sphere, fixing a point, and bulging out two horn like shapes  at the opposite side of the sphere?

Comment: What if we assume that we have nonnegative curvature?

Comment: On a thin cylinder most geodesic circles have two components. You can take a long section of a cylinder and cap it off to get a sphere with non-negative curvature.

Comment: I'm wondering if it possible to find a point where the statement is true.

Comment: ...(assuming convexity if necessary)

Comment: convexity of what?

Comment: Convexity of $S^2$, i.e. nonnegative curvature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us make this question less mathematical. If you think that the sphere is the earth, and your point $p$ is a village in a valley surrounded by several mountains, your set $S(p,r)$ is the set of point at the same distance from your village. If the distance tow the top of two mountains are say $d, d'$, then the set $S(p, r)$  will consist of a least two closed curves : the points at the distance $d-r$ to the top of the first mountain and another set consisting of point on the second mountain at the distance $d'-r$ to the summit. You can make this example more complicated by requiring several mountains, or asking that the distance to the two summits are exactly the same, and looking what happens at the mountain pass...

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering the following: If we assume nonnegative curvature, can we find a point such that $S(p,r)$ will always be connected? (I know this is different from the question I asked initially.)